# Using query to set the column type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

After the excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336259/how-to-query-the-schema-details-of-a-table-in-postgres) by Alexandre GUIDET, I attempted to run the following query:

```
 create table egg (id (SELECT 
  pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as Datatype 
  FROM 
  pg_catalog.pg_attribute a 
  WHERE 
    a.attnum > 0 
  AND NOT a.attisdropped 
  AND a.attrelid = ( 
    SELECT c.oid 
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c 
    LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace 
    WHERE c.relname ~ '^(TABLENAME)$' 
   AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid) 
  ) 
  and a.attname = 'COLUMNNAME'));
```

PostgreSQL, however, complains about incorrect syntax. Specifically it says that I cannot write: `create table egg (id (SELECT`.
Are there any workarounds? Can't I convert the result of a query to text and reuse it as a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a **much simpler** way to do that.

```
SELECT pg_typeof(col)::text FROM tbl LIMIT 1
```

Only precondition is that the template table holds *at least one row*. See the [manual on pg_typeof()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html)

As Milen wrote, you need to `EXECUTE` dynamic DDL statements like this.
A much simpler `DO` statement:

```
DO $$BEGIN
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE egg (id '
         || (SELECT pg_typeof(col)::text FROM tbl LIMIT 1) || ')';
END$$;
```

Or, if you are not sure the template table has any rows:

```
DO $$BEGIN
EXECUTE (
   SELECT format('CREATE TABLE egg (id %s)'
               , format_type(atttypid, atttypmod))
   FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = 'tbl'::regclass  -- name of template table
   AND    attname = 'col'             -- name of template column
   AND    attnum > 0 AND NOT attisdropped
   );
END$$;
```

These conditions seem redundant, since you look for a specific column any

[`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) requires Postgres 9.1+.

Related:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

Answer (score 1):

You can either convert that query to a [function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) or (if you have Postgres 9.0) to [an anonymous code block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html):

```
DO $$DECLARE the_type text;
BEGIN
    SELECT ... AS datatype INTO the_type FROM <the rest of your query>;
    EXECUTE 'create table egg ( id ' || the_type || <the rest of your create table statement>;
END$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a table a definition or a query, but not both. Maybe your thinking of the `select into` command.