# How to check if a table exists in a given schema

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, information-schema, search-path

Postgres 8.4 and greater databases contain common tables in `public` schema and company specific tables in `company` schema.
`company` schema names always start with `'company'` and end with the company number.
So there may be schemas like:

```
public
company1
company2
company3
...
companynn
```

An application always works with a single company.
The `search_path` is specified accordingly in odbc or npgsql connection string, like:

```
search_path='company3,public'
```

How would you check if a given table exists in a specified `companyn` schema?

eg:

```
select isSpecific('company3','tablenotincompany3schema')
```

should return `false`, and

```
select isSpecific('company3','tableincompany3schema')
```

should return `true`.

In any case, the function should check only `companyn` schema passed, not other schemas.

If a given table exists in both `public` and the passed schema, the function should return `true`.
It should work for Postgres 8.4 or later.

Comment: IF EXISTS ... IF NOT EXISTS .. without [ ]

Answer (score 413, accepted):

It depends on what you want to test ***exactly***.

#### Information schema?

To find "whether the table exists" (*no matter who's asking*), querying the information schema (`information_schema.tables`) is **incorrect**, strictly speaking, because ([per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-tables.html)):

> Only those tables and views are shown that the current user has access
> to (by way of being the owner or having some privilege).

The query [provided by @kong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20584058/939860) can return `FALSE`, but the table can still exist. It answers the question:

***How to check whether a table (or view) exists, and the current user has access to it?***

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM information_schema.tables 
   WHERE  table_schema = 'schema_name'
   AND    table_name   = 'table_name'
   );
```

The information schema is mainly useful to stay portable across major versions and across different RDBMS. But the implementation is slow, because Postgres has to use sophisticated views to comply to the standard (`information_schema.tables` is a rather simple example). And some information (like OIDs) gets lost in translation from the system catalogs - which *actually* carry all information.

#### System catalogs

Your question was:

***How to check whether a table exists?***

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
   JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
   WHERE  n.nspname = 'schema_name'
   AND    c.relname = 'table_name'
   AND    c.relkind = 'r'    -- only tables
   );
```

Use the system catalogs `pg_class` and `pg_namespace` directly, which is also considerably faster. However, [per documentation on `pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html):

> The catalog `pg_class` catalogs tables and most everything else that has
> columns or is otherwise similar to a table. This includes **indexes** (but
> see also `pg_index`), **sequences**, **views**, **materialized views**, **composite
> types**, and **TOAST tables**;

For this particular question you can also use the [system view **`pg_tables`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-tables.html). A bit simpler and more portable across major Postgres versions (which is hardly of concern for this basic query):

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM pg_tables
   WHERE  schemaname = 'schema_name'
   AND    tablename  = 'table_name'
   );
```

Identifiers have to be unique among *all* objects mentioned above. If you want to ask:

***How to check whether a name for a table or similar object in a given schema is taken?***

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
   JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
   WHERE  n.nspname = 'schema_name'
   AND    c.relname = 'table_name'
   );
```

- [Related answer on dba.SE discussing **"Information schema vs. system catalogs"**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75124/3684)

### Alternative: cast to [**`regclass`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html)

```
SELECT 'schema_name.table_name'::regclass;
```

This *raises an exception* if the (optionally schema-qualified) table (or other object occupying that name) does not exist.

If you do not schema-qualify the table name, a cast to `regclass` defaults to the [**`search_path`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860) and returns the OID for the first table found - or an exception if the table is in none of the listed schemas. Note that the system schemas `pg_catalog` and `pg_temp` (the schema for temporary objects of the current session) are automatically part of the `search_path`.

You can use that and catch a possible exception in a function. Example:

- [Check if sequence exists in Postgres (plpgsql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905868/Check-if-sequence-exists-in-Postgres-plpgsql/11919600#11919600)

A query like above avoids possible exceptions and is therefore slightly faster.

Note that the each component of the name is treated as **identifier** here - as opposed to above queries where names are given as literal strings. Identifiers are cast to lower case unless double-quoted. If you have forced otherwise illegal identifiers with double-quotes, those need to be included. Like:

```
SELECT '"Dumb_SchName"."FoolishTbl"'::regclass;
```

See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

### [`to_regclass(rel_name)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) in Postgres 9.4+

Much simpler now:

```
SELECT to_regclass('schema_name.table_name');
```

Same as the cast, [**but** it returns ...](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE)

> ... null rather than throwing an error if the name is not found

Comment: from shell: `[[ \`psql dbname -tAc "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'ejabberd' AND table_name = 'users');"\` = 't' ]]`

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using [pg_tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/view-pg-tables.html)?

Comment: `pg_tables` is actually a good idea for *"How to check whether a table exists?"* (Checking for *tables only*, not for other purposes, like explained above. Also, `pg_tables` is a view involving several tables (`pg_class`, `pg_namespace`, `pg_tablespace`), which is a bit more expensive. The most important reason: I am used to query `pg_class` directly and didn't think of `pg_tables` when writing this answer. I added it above now, thanks.

Comment: If you need to do this for a temp table use "and table_schema like 'pg_temp_%'"

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter That doesn't work (at least in postgres 9.4). Postgres uses pg_temp_ as a namespace for temp table schemas and then suffixes them with a number. I just wrote a unittest for this, so I figured I'd keep someone else from that same pitfall.

Comment: @sage88: Right, I removed my incorrect comment. You can use [`pg_my_temp_schema()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE) to get the OID of the actual temp schema if it exists. (But views in the `information_schema` don't include OIDs. You could `SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace WHERE OID = pg_my_temp_schema()`) Your test has several weaknesses. A correct test would be `table_schema LIKE 'pg\_temp\_%'` or stricter: `table_schema ~ '^pg_temp_\d+$'`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Now that is superior. Going to switch over to doing a subquery for the nspname, thank you!

Comment: ERROR with `SELECT to_regclass('schema_name.table_name'::text)` , to_regclass(text) does not exist.... Not make sense and will impossible to use in a function.

Comment: @PeterKrauss You will get that error if you try to use the to_regclass function on a version of postgres older than 9.4. Must have 9.4+

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: please move the `to_regclass` answer to the top, or make a separate answer of it, so that it can be voted to top!

Comment: Small addition regarding `to_regclass`: I had to set the names within double quotes (`'"schema_name"."table_name"'`) to get a response not being null

Comment: @AndreS.: Yes, worth pointing out, thank you. I added notes above.

Answer (score 55):

Perhaps use [information_schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/infoschema-tables.html):

```
SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE 
      table_schema = 'company3' AND 
      table_name = 'tableincompany3schema'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

### For PostgreSQL 9.3 or less...Or who likes all normalized to text

Three flavors of my old SwissKnife library: `relname_exists(anyThing)`, `relname_normalized(anyThing)` and `relnamechecked_to_array(anyThing)`. All checks from *pg_catalog.pg_class* table, and returns standard universal datatypes (*boolean*, *text* or *text*[]).

```
/**
 * From my old SwissKnife Lib to your SwissKnife. License CC0.
 * Check and normalize to array the free-parameter relation-name.
 * Options: (name); (name,schema), ("schema.name"). Ignores schema2 in ("schema.name",schema2).
 */
CREATE FUNCTION relname_to_array(text,text default NULL) RETURNS text[] AS $f$
     SELECT array[n.nspname::text, c.relname::text]
     FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace,
            regexp_split_to_array($1,'\.') t(x) -- not work with quoted names
     WHERE  CASE
              WHEN COALESCE(x[2],'')>'' THEN n.nspname = x[1]      AND c.relname = x[2]
              WHEN $2 IS NULL THEN           n.nspname = 'public'  AND c.relname = $1
              ELSE                           n.nspname = $2        AND c.relname = $1
            END
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION relname_exists(text,text default NULL) RETURNS boolean AS $wrap$
  SELECT EXISTS (SELECT relname_to_array($1,$2))
$wrap$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION relname_normalized(text,text default NULL,boolean DEFAULT true) RETURNS text AS $wrap$
  SELECT COALESCE(array_to_string(relname_to_array($1,$2), '.'), CASE WHEN $3 THEN '' ELSE NULL END)
$wrap$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
```