# Check if table is empty in runtime

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to write a script which drops some obsolete tables in Postgres database. I want to be sure the tables are empty before dropping them. I also want the script could be kept in our migration scripts  where it is safe to run even after these tables are actually dropped.

There is my script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION __execute(TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
  BEGIN EXECUTE $1; END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION __table_exists(TEXT, TEXT) RETURNS bool as $$
SELECT exists(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE (table_schema, table_name, table_type) = ($1, $2, 'BASE TABLE'));
$$ language sql STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION __table_is_empty(TEXT) RETURNS bool as $$
  SELECT not exists(SELECT 1 FROM  $1 ); 
$$ language sql STRICT;

-- Start migration here

SELECT __execute($$
   DROP TABLE oldtable1;
$$)
WHERE __table_exists('public', 'oldtable1')
 AND __table_is_empty('oldtable1');

-- drop auxilary functions here
```

And finally I got:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
> LINE 11:   SELECT not exists(SELECT 1 FROM  $1 );
> ```

Is there any other way?

Comment: you can use select count(*) from table name if result is 0 that means table is empty and you can delete.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is in from clause syntax rather that emptyness test method

Comment: An empty table can still be in use by some other proces, doing some inserts or deletes that have not yet been committed. Check the current processes using this table as well.

Comment: It is example of dynamic sql .. sql query that is created in run-time. This feature is not supported by SQL language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `EXECUTE` if you want to pass a table name as parameter in a Postgres function.
Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION __table_is_empty(param character varying) 
RETURNS bool
AS $$
DECLARE
 v int;
BEGIN
      EXECUTE 'select 1 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM ' || quote_ident(param) || ' ) '
            INTO v;
      IF v THEN return false; ELSE return true; END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
/
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/09cb0/1

Answer (score 3):

No, no, no. For many reasons.

[@kordirko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26944582/939860) already pointed out the immediate cause for the error message: In plain SQL, variables can only be used for *values* not for *key words* or *identifiers*. You can fix that with [**dynamic SQL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plpgsql+dynamic-sql), but that still doesn't make your code right.

You are applying **programming paradigms** from other programming languages. With PL/pgSQL, it is *extremely* inefficient to split your code into multiple separate tiny sub-functions. The overhead is huge in comparison.

Your actual call is also a time bomb. Expressions in the `WHERE` clause are executed **in any order**, so this may or may not raise an exception for non-existing table names:

```
WHERE __table_exists('public', 'oldtable1')
 AND __table_is_empty('oldtable1');
```

... which will roll back your whole transaction.

Finally, you are completely open to race conditions. Like [@Frank already commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943904/check-if-table-is-empty-in-runtime/26945929#comment42432387_26943904), a table can be in use by concurrent transactions, in which case open locks may stall your attempt to drop the table. Could also lead to deadlocks (which the system resolves by rolling back all but one competing transactions). Take out an **exclusive lock** yourself, *before* you check whether the table is (still) empty.

#### Proper function

This is **safe for concurrent use**. It takes an array of table names (and optionally a schema name) and only drops existing, empty tables that are not locked in any way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_drop_tables(_tbls text[] = '{}'
                                       , _schema text = 'public'
                                       , OUT drop_ct int)  AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tbl   text;                             -- loop var
   _empty bool;                             -- for empty check
BEGIN
   drop_ct := 0;                            -- init!
   FOR _tbl IN 
      SELECT quote_ident(table_schema) || '.'
          || quote_ident(table_name)        -- qualified & escaped table name
      FROM   information_schema.tables
      WHERE  table_schema = _schema
      AND    table_type   = 'BASE TABLE'
      AND    table_name   = ANY(_tbls)
   LOOP
      EXECUTE 'SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' || _tbl || ')'
      INTO _empty;                          -- check first, only lock if empty

      IF _empty THEN
         EXECUTE 'LOCK TABLE ' || _tbl;     -- now table is ripe for the plucking

         EXECUTE 'SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' || _tbl || ')'
         INTO _empty;                       -- recheck after lock

         IF _empty THEN
            EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE ' || _tbl;  -- go in for the kill
            drop_ct := drop_ct + 1;         -- count tables actually dropped
         END IF;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_drop_tables('{foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4}');
```

To call with a different schema than the default 'public':

```
SELECT f_drop_tables('{foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4}', 'my_schema');
```

#### Major points

- Reports the number of tables actually dropped. (Adapt to report info of your choice.)
- Using the **information schema** like in your original. Seems the right choice here, but be aware of subtle limitations:

  - [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)
- For use under heavy concurrent load (with long transactions), consider the [**`NOWAIT`** option for the `LOCK` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-lock.html) and possibly catch exceptions from it.
- [Per documentation on **"Table-level Locks"**:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES)

> `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE`
>
> Conflicts with locks of all modes (`ACCESS SHARE`, `ROW SHARE`, `ROW EXCLUSIVE`, 
>   `SHARE UPDATE` `EXCLUSIVE`, `SHARE`, `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE`, `EXCLUSIVE`,
>   and `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE`). This mode guarantees that the holder
>   is the only transaction accessing the table in any way.
>
> Acquired by the `ALTER TABLE`, `DROP TABLE`, `TRUNCATE`, `REINDEX`, `CLUSTER`, and `VACUUM FULL` commands. This is also the
>   default lock mode for **`LOCK TABLE` statements that do not specify a mode explicitly**.

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: wow! Indeed my solution depend on order of execution. But naively, as a java programmer, I think the analyser assigns minimal cost to the fetching from fully cached system table and preserve my order of the execution as the analysing of another function is hardly possible. 
Locking is also not a problem in our case. We are trying to drop traces of the outdated design and expect all data are migrated to new tables. It is all we need to ensure, we know there are no code which could read these tables. Anyway, your function really shows differences in OOP and SQL programming.

Comment: @Erwin - good answer, but without explanation of dynamic SQL, that is not available in PL/pgSQL. This query has two issues: 1) using wrong language (and wrong syntax), 2) possible race condition.

Comment: @Ervin, after cafe I found so your answer is good, query was messy

Answer (score -2):

I work on DB2 so I can't say for sure if this will work on a Postgres database, but try this:

```
select case when count(*) > 0 then True else False end from $1
```

...in place of:

```
SELECT not exists(SELECT 1 FROM  $1 )
```

If Postgres does not have a CASE / END expression capability, I'd be shocked if it didn't have some kind  of similar IF/THEN/ELSE like expression ability to use as a substitute.

Comment: An empty table can still be in use by some other proces, doing some inserts or deletes that have not yet been committed.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: I think taking out an explicit lock could solve this properly and added another answer.

Comment: This replay is nonsense. It doesn't help to solve a problem, and propose a problematic solution. Using `count` for value detection is wrong from performance perspective.