# FOR loop on PLpgSQL function result

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I wrote a PLpgSQL function which should return `SETOF products` table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_products_by_category
(selected_category_id smallint DEFAULT 1) RETURNS SETOF products AS
$BODY

$BEGIN
RETURN QUERY  (SELECT * FROM products WHERE CategoryID = selected_category_id);
END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
```

And next I want to iterate over results in another function (non-finished view, because I try to add in PgAdmin III and I have errors):

```
DECLARE
    R RECORD;
BEGIN
IF TG_TABLE_NAME != 'Categories' THEN
    RAISE 'This trigger function is for Categories, but was called for %', TG_TABLE_NAME;
FOR R IN get_products_by_category(1) LOOP
    UPDATE products SET CategoryID = NEW.id WHERE id = R.id;
RETURN NEW;
```

The idea is that I have some Products in database, which have default Category ID as 1. And then, when new Category is added, trigger is fired which update `CategoryID` (from freshly added object) for Products with default `CategoryID` - maybe it sounds stupid but I am learning triggers with Northwind Database and I had to create task for myself. :)

But I can't save it, because of errors `near get_products_by_category(1)`.
Is in PLpgSQL (I am using 9.3 version) any possibility to write something like in Java:

```
for (Product product: dao.getProductsByCategory(categoryId))
```

Updated code:

```
DECLARE
    selected_products products[];
    product products;
BEGIN
IF TG_TABLE_NAME != 'categories' THEN
    RAISE 'This trigger function is for Categories, but was called for %', TG_TABLE_NAME;
END IF;
selected_products := get_products_by_category(1);
FOR product IN selected_products LOOP
    UPDATE products SET CategoryID = NEW.id
        WHERE id = R.id;
END LOOP;
RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Comment: `IF TG_TABLE_NAME != 'Categories' THEN ...` Avoid the mixed case in names. Without quoting they will be folded to lowercase. (how was your `Categories` table defined ?)

Comment: @wildplasser I corrected it (and also added forgotten END IF etc), but it still won't work, still it looks like there is mistake in `FOR product`, but I can't see anything wrong

Comment: IIUC you don't need the loop. Just do a `UPDATE products SET CategoryID = NEW.id WHERE CategoryID = 1;` (BTW: 1 is an ugly sentinel value, IMHO)

Comment: @wildplasser Hm... I am not a SQL pro, and now when I rethink it you are right I don't need even function which takes Products by Category ID :) And 1 is bad value, but this is not a production code - it is only for educational purposes (as all task- even if I don't need FOR and function, still I need task which includes function and FOR loop to learn it :) )

Comment: You can learn (and use) SQL without loops and cursors for many years. Once you need them, you'll notice... Triggers are a bit different, because some  constraints cannot be expressed without them. (but in most cases this is an indication of a data-modelling problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to read this chapter in the manual: [**Looping Through Query Results**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).
And about [plpgsql trigger functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_trigger_func()
   RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _prod products;
BEGIN
   IF TG_TABLE_NAME <> 'categories' THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Trigger func for "categories", not for %', TG_TABLE_NAME;
   END IF;

   FOR _prod IN 
      SELECT * FROM get_products_by_category(1)
   LOOP
      UPDATE products p
      SET    categoryid = NEW.id
      WHERE  p.id = _prod.id;
   END LOOP;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Or:

```
...
DECLARE
    _id int;
BEGIN
   ...
   FOR _id IN 
      SELECT id FROM get_products_by_category(1)
   LOOP
      ...
      WHERE  p.id = _id;
...
```

Both just as proof of concept. Most of the time, there is a superior set-based solution around the corner. Like here:

```
UPDATE products p
SET    categoryid = NEW.id
FROM   get_products_by_category(1) x
WHERE  p.id = x.id;
```

You can use a set-returning function like `get_products_by_category(1)` just like you would use a table in most contexts.

#### Notes

- You must understand dollar-quoting:

  - [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)
- `!=` is valid, too, but rather use the SQL standard operator `<>`.
- Table names are not unique. to be sure you must check `TG_TABLE_NAME` and `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA`.

  - [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)