# PL/pgSQL: How to assign a table's column to a declared parameter?

Tags: postgresql, variable-assignment, plpgsql

Look at this simple PL/pgSQL function:

```
create or replace function test() returns void()
as $$
declare 
a int;
begin
select more_than_one_value into a from my_table;
-- do some other job using a
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

When calling this function, only *one* row is selected because `select into` pass only one value to `a`, even though column `more_than_one_value` has many values.

Are there any convenient ways to select many values from a table and then assigned them to variable `a` ? I know `create temp table as select` is one method. I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: You could store them in an array. But if you want to insert those values into `another_table` anyway, just do`insert into another_table (col_1) select some_column from my_table` no need for a loop and **much** faster

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from)

Comment: you can do `select a,b,c,d into a1,b1,c1,d1 from my_table limit 1;` define as many variables as you need.

Comment: I assume by `column more_than_one_value has many values` you mean that the table  `my_table` has many rows? BTW, `a` has not been declared in your example, neither as parameter nor as variable.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options you can use:

- You can use multiple variables in one `INTO` clause:

  ```
  SELECT f1, f2, f3, f4 INTO v1, v2, v3, v4 FROM ...
  ```
- You can use a record type:

  ```
  DECLARE
   a my_table%rowtype
  BEGIN
   SELECT * INTO a FROM my_table WHERE ...
   INSERT INTO another_table VALUES (a.*);
   ...
  ```
- Or forget about variables altogether:

  ```
  INSERT INTO another_table
   SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ...
  ```

Comment: First , thank you very much.     1. Multiple variables  is a good choice, but if there are 10000 rows in a table, then I have to define 10000 variables that all the values can be assigned.    2. even though a record type is used , only one record will be extracted. Well, I wish to extract more than row.  3. I konw this is the right way to perform data modification, but the question is not about insert.

Comment: You would never use a variable per row. Instead, you get one row, process it and move on to the next row. You use an explicit `CURSOR` or loop over a query's result. That is the standard way of working in `plpgsql`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a ***loop*** for that.

#### Multiple rows

If *"many values"* is supposed to mean ***multiple rows*** I suggest a [`FOR` loop](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) with an implicit cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_rows()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   i int;  -- scalar variable
BEGIN
   FOR i IN  -- repeated assignment
      SELECT more_than_one_value FROM my_table
   LOOP
      -- do something with i
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In many cases, there is superior set-based solution (plain SQL) to replace the loop.

The data type of column `more_than_one_value` must match the type of the variable (or parameter) or you get an error in the assignment.

`i` is a *variable* here, not a *parameter*. The latter term would refer to a variable passed to the function in the call.

- [Postgres FOR LOOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145761/postgres-for-loop/19147320#19147320)
- [FOR loop on PLpgSQL function result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880469/for-loop-on-plpgsql-function-result/29885625#29885625)

#### Array

If *"many values"* is supposed to mean ***array***, I suggest [`FOREACH`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_arr()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   i int[];   -- array variable
   elem int;  -- scalar variable
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO i more_than_one_value
   FROM my_table LIMIT 1; -- assign single array column

   FOREACH elem IN ARRAY i
   LOOP
      -- do something with elem
   END LOOP;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- [Postgres - array for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783422/postgres-array-for-loop/9784986#9784986)

Comment: So that means there are no convenient ways to assign multiple values to a variable? Because I saw loop , a control structure,  is used in your  answer.

Comment: @k.xf: `multiple values to a variable` - what is that supposed to mean? A field, variable or parameter  has *one* value. Are you talking about multiple rows or arrays or what is it you are talking about?