# Why does a PostgreSQL SELECT query return different results when a schema name is specified?

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, postgresql-9.2, database-permissions, search-path

I have a PostgreSQL database table with 4 columns - labeled column_a, column_b, etc.  I want to query this table with a simple select query:

```
select * from table_name;
```

I get a handful of results looking like:

```
column_a | column_b
---------+---------
'a value'|'b_value'
```

But when I use this query:

```
select * from schema_name.table_name;
```

I get the full result:

```
column_a | column_b | column_c | column_d
---------+----------+----------+---------
'a value'|'b value' |'c value' |'d_value'
```

Columns `c` and `d` were added at a later date, after initial table creation.  My question is:  Why would the database ignore the later columns when the schema name is left out of the select query?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two tables (or views) with the same name, in different schemas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Table names are not unique within a database in Postgres. There can be any number of tables named 'table_name' in different schemas - including the temporary schema, which always comes first unless you explicitly list it after other schemas in the `search_path`. Obviously, there are **multiple tables named `table_name`**. You must understand the role of the **`search_path`** to interpret this correctly:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

The first table lives in a schema that comes before `schema_name` in your `search_path` (or `schema_name` is not listed there at all). So the unqualified table name is resolved to this table (or view). Check the list of tables named 'table_name' that your current role has access to in your database:

```
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.tables 
WHERE  table_name = 'table_name';
```

Views are just special tables with an attached `RULE` internally. They could play the same role as a regular table and are included in the above query. 
Details:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

Comment: This led me to discover that a handful of tables with duplicate names had been inadvertently placed in the public schema.  Thanks.