# Trigger | how to delete row instead of update based on cell value

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

**Postgresql 10/11.**
I need to delete row instead of update in case if target cell value is `null`.

So I created this trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_on_update_related_table() RETURNS trigger
AS $$
    DECLARE
        refColumnName text = TG_ARGV[0];
    BEGIN
        IF TG_NARGS <> 1 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Trigger function expects 1 parameters, but got %', TG_NARGS;
        END IF;
        EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM ' || TG_TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE $1 = ''$2'''
        USING refColumnName, OLD.id;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER proper_delete
BEFORE UPDATE OF def_id
ON public.definition_products 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.def_id IS NULL)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_on_update_related_table('def_id');
```

Table is simple:

```
id  uuid primary key
def_id  uuid not null
```

Test:

```
UPDATE definition_products SET
    def_id = NULL 
WHERE id = 'f47415e8-6b00-4c65-aeb8-cadc15ca5890';
-- rows affected 0
```

Documentation says:

> Row-level triggers fired BEFORE **can return null** to signal the trigger
>   manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e.,
>   subsequent triggers are not fired, **and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does
>   not occur for this row**).

Previously, I used a `RULE` instead of the trigger. But there is no way to use `WHERE` & `RETURNING` clause in same rule.

> You need an unconditional ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD rule with a RETURNING clause

So, is there a way?

Comment: Is the query really supposed to be DELETE FROM definition_products where def_id = OLD.id as you have it?  Shouldn't it be where id = OLD.id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [Jeremy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56150773/939860) is good, there is still room for improvement.

#### Problems

You need to be *very accurate* in the definition of the objective. Your statement:

> I need to delete row instead of update in case if target cell value is null.

... does not imply that the column was changed to `NULL` in the `UPDATE` at hand. Might have been `NULL` before, like, before you implemented the trigger. So not:

```
BEFORE UPDATE OF def_id ON public.definition_products
```

But just:

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON public.definition_products
```

Of course, if the column is defined `NOT NULL` (as it probably should be), there is no effective difference - except for the noise and an additional point of failure. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html#Notes)

> A column-specific trigger (one defined using the `UPDATE OF`***`column_name`*** syntax) will fire when any of its columns are listed as targets in the `UPDATE` command's `SET` list. It is possible for a column's value to change even when the trigger is not fired, because changes made to the row's contents by `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers are not considered.

Also, nothing in your question indicates the need for dynamic SQL. (That  *would* be the case if you wanted to reuse the same trigger function for multiple triggers on different tables. And even then it's often better to just create several distinct trigger functions for multiple reason: simpler, faster, less error-prone, easier to read & maintain, ...)

As for "error-prone": your original dynamic statement was just invalid:

```
EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM ' || TG_TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE $1 = ''$2'''
    USING refColumnName, OLD.id;
```

- Can't pass a column name as *value* (`refColumnName`).
- Can't put single quotes around `$2`, which is passed as *value* and hence needs no quoting.
- An unqualified, unquoted `TG_TABLE_NAME` can go terribly wrong, which is especially critical for a heavy-weight function that deletes rows.

Jeremy's version fixes most, but still features the unqualified `TG_TABLE_NAME`.

This would be good:

```
EXECUTE format('DELETE FROM %s WHERE %I = $1', TG_RELID::regclass, refColumnName)   -- refColumnName still unquoted
USING OLD.id;
```

Or:

```
EXECUTE format('DELETE FROM %I.%I WHERE %I = $1', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME, refColumnName)
USING OLD.id;
```

Related:

- [Why does a PostgreSQL SELECT query return different results when a schema name is specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179061/why-does-a-postgresql-select-query-return-different-results-when-a-schema-name-i/30179624#30179624)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

### Solution

Simpler trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_on_update_related_table()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM public.definition_products WHERE id = OLD.id;  -- def_id?
  RETURN NULL;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Simpler trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER proper_delete
BEFORE UPDATE ON public.definition_products 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.def_id IS NULL)                            -- that's the defining condition!
EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_on_update_related_table();  -- no parameter
```

You probably want to use `OLD.id`, not `OLD.def_id`. (The row to delete is best defined by it's PK, not by the column changed to `NULL`.) But that's not entirely clear.

Comment: Thanks, using TG_RELID::regclass is indeed much better.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, with a few small changes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_on_update_related_table() RETURNS trigger
AS $$
    DECLARE
        refColumnName text = quote_ident(TG_ARGV[0]);
    BEGIN
        IF TG_NARGS <> 1 THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Trigger function expects 1 parameters, but got %', TG_NARGS; END IF;
        EXECUTE format('DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s = %s', quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME), refColumnName, quote_literal(OLD.id));
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- create trigger
CREATE TRIGGER proper_delete
BEFORE UPDATE OF def_id
ON public.definition_products 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.def_id IS NULL)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_on_update_related_table('id');   --Note id, not def_id
```

Comment: Careful with `TG_TABLE_NAME` and no schema-qualification.