# IF EXIST before many insertions in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, insert

I would like to INSERT only if table exists. 
Pseudocode

```
IF EXISTS TABLE file_headers(
INSERT INTO file_headers
(measurement_id, file_header_index_start, file_header_index_end)
VALUES (1, 1, 100);
INSERT INTO file_headers
(measurement_id, file_header_index_start, file_header_index_end)
VALUES (1, 2, 100);
... -- many INSERTs into same table
);
```

How can you insert only if the table exists in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Just run the `insert` and handle the error in your program.

Comment: This suggestion involves many stages. Any such general IF EXISTS for many INSERTs?

Comment: What's wrong with INSERT INTO file_headers
(measurement_id, file_header_index_start, file_header_index_end)
VALUES (1, 1, 100), (1, 2, 100), (1, 3, 100), ((...));?

Comment: If one insert fails, I think then many other fails too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test would make sense if you wanted to pass table names to a function for dynamic execution.

There is a built-in solution for that: if you want to make sure the table exists, cast it to **[`regclass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html)** (or use a `regclass` parameter to your function to begin with). That verifies existence and escapes possible non-standard syntax at the same time:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/939860)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)

Answer (score 2):

```
do $$begin
  if exists (select * from pg_catalog.pg_tables where tablename = 'mytable') then
     insert into mytable (col1) values (1);
  end if;
end$$;
```