# Declare row type variable in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, types, plpgsql, declare, select-into

As I found `SELECT * FROM t INTO my_data;` works only if:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
my_data t%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM t INTO my_data WHERE id = ?;
END $$;
```

Am I right?

If I want to get only 2-3 columns instead of all columns. How can I define `my_data`?

That is,

```
DO $$
DECLARE
my_data <WHAT HERE??>;
BEGIN
SELECT id,name,surname FROM t INTO my_data WHERE id = ?;
END $$;
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> get only 2-3 columns instead of all columns

One way: use a [`record`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS) variable:

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _rec record;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _rec
          id, name, surname
   FROM   t
   WHERE  id = ?;

   -- do something with it ...
END
$do$;
```

Note that the structure of a `record` type is undefined until assigned. So you cannot reference columns (fields) before you do that.

Another way: assign multiple scalar variables:

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _id int;
   _name text;
   _surname text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _id, _name, _surname
          id,  name,  surname
   FROM   t
   WHERE  id = ?;
END
$do$;
```

`%ROWTYPE` is just noise in Postgres. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ROWTYPES):

> (Since every table has an associated composite type of the same name,
> it actually does not matter in PostgreSQL whether you write `%ROWTYPE`
> or not. But the form with `%ROWTYPE` is more portable.)

So:

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   my_data t;  -- table name serves as type name, too. 
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO my_data * FROM t WHERE id = ?;
END
$do$;
```

Comment: The last part returns ERROR: relation my_data does not exist

Comment: @RajShah: If the table is not in the current `search_path`, you have to schema-qualify both instances: `my_schema.my_data` - which is the safe route in any case. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/939860