# Access and return result from INSERT INTO in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, set-returning-functions, sql-returning

I am currently learning a lot of PostgreSQL, especially `PLPGSQL` and am struggling in handling query results in functions.
I want to create a wrapper around a user table and use the result later on and then return it.
In my case the user and account are two different tables and I want to create it in one go.

My first and naïve approach was to build the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.create_user_with_login (IN email varchar, IN password varchar, IN firstname varchar DEFAULT NULL, IN surname varchar DEFAULT NULL)
    RETURNS schema.user
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    VOLATILE 
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
    AS 
$$
declare
  created_user schema."user";
begin

  INSERT INTO schema."user" ("firstname", "surname", "email")
    VALUES (firstname, surname, email)
    RETURNING * INTO created_user;

  // [...] create accounts and other data using e.g. created_user.id

  // the query should return the initially created user
  RETURN created_user
end;
$$;
```

This approach does not work, as `schema.user` has `NOT NULL` fields (a domain type with that constraint) and will throw an exception for the declared statement:

```
domain schema."USER_ID" does not allow null values
```

So maybe it could work, but not with in that constrained environment.

I also tried to use `RETURNS SETOF schema.user` and directly `RETURN QUERY INSERT ....`, but this does not return all columns, but instead one column with all the data.

How can I achieve the effect of returning the initial user object as a proper user row while having the data available inside the function?

I am using Postgres 9.6. My version output:

```
PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Issue 1

> I also tried to use `RETURNS SETOF schema.user` and directly `RETURN QUERY INSERT` ...., but this does not return all columns, but instead
>   one column with all the data.

Sure it returns all columns. You have to ***call*** set-returning functions like this:

```
SELECT * FROM schema.create_user_with_login;
```

You have to declare it as `RETURNS SETOF foo.users` to cooperate with `RETURN QUERY`.

#### Issue 2

It's nonsense to declare your function as `STRICT` (synonym for `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT`) and then declare NULL parameter default values:

```
... firstname varchar DEFAULT NULL, IN surname varchar DEFAULT NULL)
```

You *cannot* pass NULL values to a function defined `STRICT`, it would just return NULL and do nothing. While `firstname` and `surname` are meant to be optional, do *not* define the function strict (or pass empty strings instead or something)

#### More suggestions

Don't call your schema `"schema"`.
Don't use the [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) `user` as identifier at all.
Use legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers everywhere if possible.

#### Function

All things considered, your function might look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo.create_user_with_login (_email text
                                                     , _password text
                                                     , _firstname text = NULL
                                                     , _surname text = NULL)

  RETURNS SETOF foo.users
  LANGUAGE plpgsql  AS  -- do *not* define it STRICT
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   WITH u AS (
      INSERT INTO foo.users (firstname, surname, email)
      VALUES (_firstname, _surname, _email)
      RETURNING *
      )
    , a AS (       -- create account using created_user.id
      INSERT INTO accounts (user_id) 
      SELECT u.user_id FROM u
      )
      --  more chained CTEs with DML statements?
   TABLE u;        -- return the initially created user
END
$func$;
```

Yes, that's a *single* SQL statement with several data-modifying CTE to do it all. Fastest and cleanest. The function wrapper is optional for convenience. Might as well be `LANGUAGE sql`. Related:

- [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561254/insert-data-in-3-tables-at-a-time-using-postgres/20561627#20561627)

I prepended function parameter names with underscore (`_email`) to rule out naming conventions. This is totally optional, but you have carefully keep track of the scope of conflicting parameters, variables, and column names if you don't.

`TABLE u` is short for `SELECT * FROM u`.

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from-in-psql/30276023#30276023)

#### Store results of query in a plpgsql variable?

Three distinct cases:

1. Single value:

   - [Store query result in a variable using in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328198/store-the-query-result-in-variable-using-postgresql-stored-procedure/12328820)
2. Single row

   - [Declare row type variable in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913214/declare-row-type-variable-in-pl-pgsql/32913616#32913616)
3. Set of rows (= table)

There are no "table variables", but several other options:

- [PostgreSQL table variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785767/postgresql-table-variable/10790059#10790059)
- [How to use a record type variable in plpgsql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34019898/how-to-use-a-record-type-variable-in-plpgsql/34034929#34034929)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will look into this. About the declaration of a "created_user" variable, is that completely impossible our how would I store the result of the query? In a case like this I will try to do it in one query, but for my understanding I still would like to store the result somewhere.

Comment: @Maddis: I added some more above to give you an overview.

Comment: The `record` type was exactly what I was missing. Thank you very much! :)