# Deleting a row with dynamic SQL in a procedure

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

How to delete a row in a stored procedure in PostgreSQL with dynamic table and column names?
`delete_word` will be the one that should be deleted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_row(tablename VARCHAR(255),columnname VARCHAR(255), delete_word VARCHAR(255))
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM ' || quote_ident(tablename) || ' WHERE ' || columnname || ' = ' || quote_ident(delete_word);
END $$; 

CALL delete_row('sales_2019','orderid', 'Order ID');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling dynamic SQL properly:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_row(tablename text, columnname text, delete_word text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
DECLARE
   _sql text := format('DELETE FROM %I WHERE %I = $1', $1, $2);
BEGIN
   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;  -- debug first?!
   EXECUTE _sql
   USING   delete_word;
END
$proc$;
```

Call:

```
CALL delete_row('sales_2019', 'orderid', 'Order ID');
```

See:

- [Format specifier for integer variables in format() for EXECUTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656716/format-specifier-for-integer-variables-in-format-for-execute/22675836#22675836)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [How to use variable as table name in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559093/how-to-use-variable-as-table-name-in-plpgsql/35642628#35642628)

Dynamic SQL with [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) and [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) is only needed if table and column name must indeed be variable. The answer is a proof of concept for more complex tasks. A simple command like in the example, I would rather just concatenate and execute as plain SQL.

Also using data type `text` for arguments. `varchar(255)` does not do anything useful there, and generally tends to be a misunderstanding carried over from other RDBMS. See:

- [Refactor foreign key to fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558650/refactor-foreign-key-to-fields/24560486#24560486)

Comment: Noted for that, sir! I will take more research to fully more understand Dynamic SQL