# PostgreSQL check if table exist throwing "relation does not exist" error

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL I try to check if table exist:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_name);
```

And it throwing an error. How can I check if table already exists so the result will be boolean? Because currently I can achieve the same with try-catch (enters to catch if not exist) instead of if-else on the result...

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of these should work, though depending on how your permissions are set up you may not have access to the tables:

`SELECT EXISTS (SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'table_name');`

`SELECT EXISTS (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'table_name');`