# PostgreSQL transactional DDL and to_regclass

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, transactional-database

Following the suggestion at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema), I'm using the `to_regclass` function to check if a table exists, creating it if it doesn't.  However, it appears that if the table was created in the current transaction, `to_regclass` still returns `null`.

Is this behaviour expected?  Or is this a bug?

**Detail**

Here's a short example of where this goes wrong:

```
begin;
create schema test;
create table test.test ( id serial, category integer );

create or replace function test.test_insert () returns trigger as $$
declare
    child_table_name text;
    table_id     text;
begin
    child_table_name = concat('test.test_', text(new.category));
    table_id = to_regclass(child_table_name::cstring);
    if table_id is null then
        execute format('create table %I ( primary key (id), check ( category = %L ) ) inherits (test.test)', child_table_name, new.category);
    end if;
    execute format ('insert into %I values ($1.*)', child_table_name) using new;
    return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger test_insert before insert on test.test for each row execute procedure test.test_insert();

insert into test.test (category) values (1);
insert into test.test (category) values (1);
insert into test.test (category) values (1);
commit;
```

Comment: And why don't you simply use `create table if not exists`?

Comment: Er... yes, you've got me there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `%I` format specifier incorrectly.

If your category is `1`, then you end up calling `to_regclass('test.test_1')`, i.e. checking for the table `test_1` in schema `test`.

However, `format('create table %I', 'test.test_1')` will treat the format argument as a single identifier and quote it accordingly, evaluating to `'create table "test.test_1"'`. This will create a table called `"test.test_1"` in your default schema (probably `public`).

Instead, you need to treat your schema and table names as separate identifiers. Define your table name as:

```
child_table_name = format('test.%I', 'test_' || new.category);
```

... and when building your SQL strings, just substitute this value directly (i.e. with `%s` rather than `%I`).

Comment: Many thanks.  I wouldn't have spotted that in a million years.