# How to list the columns of a view in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For a physical table, I have been using the following SQL:

```
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = 'a_table_name'
```

I found that this doesn't work for a view. Is there a way to get the schema of a view by running a SQL command (not via psql).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Postgres has dedicated [System Catalog Information Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to help with that.

To get the full **view definition**:

```
SELECT pg_get_viewdef('public.view_name');
```

Schema-qualification is optional. If no schema is prefixed, the current `search_path` setting decides visibility.

A **quick hack** would be to just:

```
SELECT * FROM public.view_name LIMIT 0;
```

Depending on your client, column names and types should still be displayed. Or `LIMIT n` to get some sample values, too. The underlying query is actually executed then (unlike with `LIMIT 0`).

To **list columns and their data type**, in order, you might base the query on [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html):

```sql
SELECT attname AS column_name, format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) AS data_type
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'public.view_name'::regclass
-- AND    NOT attisdropped
-- AND    attnum > 0
ORDER  BY attnum;
```

Type modifiers like maximum length are included in `data_type` this way.

Internally, a `VIEW` is implemented as special table with a rewrite rule. [Details in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-views.html) The table is saved in the system catalogs much like any regular table.

About the cast to `regclass`:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

The same query works for tables or materialized views as well. Uncomment the additional filters above to only get visible user columns for tables.

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT
    a.attname,
    t.typname,
    a.atttypmod
FROM pg_class c
INNER JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
INNER JOIN pg_type t ON t.oid = a.atttypid
WHERE c.relkind = 'v'
    AND c.relname = 'put_viewname_here';
```

**ATTENTION**: Since the viewname is unique only in the schema, you might also want to add an `INNER JOIN` to `pg_namespace` and add a condition to the where-clause.

---

For the first version of your question:

```sql
SELECT n.nspname
FROM pg_class c
INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind = 'v'
    AND c.relname = 'put_viewname_here';
```

**ATTENTION**: This might give you multiple schemas, since a viewname is only unique inside a schema and thus a viewname does not always identify one view.