# How to bind a variable in Postgres functions?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.view_columns_f(viewname text)
 RETURNS TABLE(columnn_name text, data_type text)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    return query execute
    $$SELECT attname, format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) AS data_type
    FROM   pg_attribute
    WHERE  attrelid = '$1'::regclass$$
    using viewname;
END;
```

The error is relation "$1" doesn't exist, because I'm not binding it correctly.

Comment: Three errors  1) You don't have a closing `$function$` after the `END`; 2) The '$$ .. $$' around the query is not needed.  3) The `'$1'` should be just `$1`.  See [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) and [Return query](43.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY) 43.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY.

Comment: That should have been [Return query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) 43.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adrian pointed out a couple of problems, I fixed a couple more:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.view_columns_f(viewname regclass)
  RETURNS TABLE (columnn_name name, data_type text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT attname, format_type(atttypid, atttypmod)  -- AS data_type
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = $1
   AND    NOT attisdropped  -- exclude deleted columns
   AND    attnum > 0        -- exclude internal system columns
   ORDER  BY attnum;        -- original order
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM public.view_columns_f('my_view');
```

Most importantly, you don't need dynamic SQL at all, luckily. Get a grip on plain PL/pgSQL first, before playing with trickier dynamic SQL.

Could be a simpler SQL function, nothing *requires* PL/pgSQL.

The function name is misleading. You get columns for any registered relation this way, not just for a view.

Further reading:

- [How to list the columns of a view in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020428/how-to-list-the-columns-of-a-view-in-postgres/58020843#58020843)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)