# Find columns based on row data postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I am interacting with a huge Postgres database that I am not familiar with. This database exposes large views with hundreds of columns each. I am supposed to get the column that contains a `store ID`, but I do not know the name of the column and it may be something generic (like `customfield1`).

Is there a way to do a reverse, by-data lookup of a column in PostgreSQL? [This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020428/how-to-list-the-columns-of-a-view-in-postgres) shows how to get the column names for a given view, but somehow I have to join that to the data that I search for in the table.

I want something essentially like this pseudo-sql:

```sql
select column_name from "columns_in_view" where content_of_column like "%VNMI%"
```

where I can test against an arbitrary string and find the column that contains data like that string.

If the only way is downloading the table as a CSV that's fine, but a SQL query is much more ideal as I do not want to expose myself to more customer information than necessary for security reasons.

I'd be open to a python solution as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list the columns of a view in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020428/how-to-list-the-columns-of-a-view-in-postgres)

Comment: @bfris No, but I appreciate it. I've edited my question, hopefully to make it clear what the distinction is.