# How can I determine if a postgres temporary table was created?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2, create-table

When running a query that creates a temporary table if it doesn't exist, how do I determine if a new table was actually created?

For example if I create a temporary table with `CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name` can I get the query to return something if a new table was created or not?

In my specific case, upon creating a temporary table I then run another query to copy some data to it so I need to ensure that I am only copying the data if the temporary table was recreated (if for example the table was dropped because of some momentary connection drop out or something). I am using psycopg2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema)

Comment: No it doesn't because I don't think that answer applies to temporary tables

Comment: eventually I used SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   information_schema.tables 
   WHERE  table_schema like 'pg_temp_%'
   AND table_name=LOWER('table_name')
)

Answer (score 0):

You should test if your table exists **before** you execute the query "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS". For example with this query :

```sql
    SELECT 1 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema='YourShema' AND table_name='TableName';
```

If the table did not exist before, this means she has been created after ! ;)

An other solution is to not use the "IF NOT EXISTS" directive and catch the exception if table already exists.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it about temporary tables because this query cannot be used to to test if a temporary table exists (I tested it)