# Filter column names from existing table for SQL DDL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

Is it possible to filter on column names themselves in psql? I want to generate a limited version of the original table (with several hundred columns) in a separate schema a la (pseudocode):

```
create table why.am_i_doing_this
    select *
    from original.table 
    where column_name_of_the_table not in ('column_1', 'column_2' );
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  It is not clear what you really want to do.

Comment: Let's say I have a table schema_1.original_table (A text, B text, C text). I want to run something like

create table schema_2.new_table as select * from schema_1.original_table where column_name NOT IN (A, B);

I am basically looking to see if there is a way to "deselect" columns I am not interested in from the original table rather than having to put down all of the 300-odd column names I am interested in within a single create table query if that makes sense.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no simple way to do that in Postgres.

Comment: I figured as much. Been fiddling around with it for the best part of the last hour or two. Do you have any idea what a not so simple approach could look like by any chance?

Comment: It's pretty simple after all ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . Dynamic SQL is not a simple solution.  BigQuery's `except` syntax is a simple solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: True, dynamic SQL in a `DO` statement is not entirely simple. But that's just the cherry on top. The basic statement is simple enough. And while at the topic of simplicity, I added `\gexec` ... (BTW, I'd love BigQuery's `EXCEPT` in standard SQL!)

Answer (score 1):

Build the DDL command dynamically. You can do it in two steps:

1. Build statement:

   ```
   SELECT 'CREATE TABLE why.am_i_doing_this AS SELECT '
       || string_agg(column_name, ', ' ORDER BY ordinal_position)
       || ' FROM original.table'
   FROM   information_schema.columns
   WHERE  table_schema = 'original'
   AND    table_name = 'table'
   AND    column_name NOT IN ('column_1', 'column_2');
   ```
2. (Check it's good!) Then execute the generated statement in a second round trip to the server.

This is based on the information schema view [`information_schema.columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html). Alternatively, you could use [`pg_catalog.pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html). Related:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

But it can be done in a single round trip to the server, too:

#### With a `DO` statement from any client

`DO` is just a simple wrapper for ad-hoc execution of PL/pgSQL code. You might do the same in a function or procedure.

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
   SELECT 'CREATE TABLE why.am_i_doing_this AS SELECT '
       || string_agg(column_name, ', ' ORDER BY ordinal_position)
       || ' FROM original.table'
   FROM   information_schema.columns
   WHERE  table_schema = 'original'
   AND    table_name = 'table'
   AND    column_name NOT IN ('column_1', 'column_2')
   );
END
$$;
```

#### Simpler with psql meta-command `\gexec`

Since you mentioned the [default interactive terminal `psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). There you can use `\gexec`. It ...

> Sends the current query buffer to the server, then treats each column of each row of the query's output (if any) as a SQL statement to be executed.

So:

```
SELECT 'CREATE TABLE why.am_i_doing_this AS SELECT '
    || string_agg(column_name, ', ' ORDER BY ordinal_position)
    || ' FROM original.table'
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_schema = 'original'
AND    table_name = 'table'
AND    column_name NOT IN ('column_1', 'column_2')\gexec
```