# How to refer to a value in a PostgreSQL script?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, psql, dynamic-sql

I'd like to use the max value to feed the creation of a sequence. For instance, I am getting the max id value and I'd like to use this value:

```
DO $$
DECLARE   
    min_value Integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(tmp.id)+1 into min_value FROM tmp;
    -- raise notice 'Value: %', min_value;
    
    CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq_tmp
    INCREMENT 1
    START :tmp.min_value --Getting error: syntax error at or near ":"
    MINVALUE :tmp.min_value;
END $$;
```

How do I refer to the max value and pass to the sequence creation? I am using psql (PostgreSQL) 13.3.

Comment: "Postgresql script" is unclear. Do you mean the `DO` command (which is an SQL command) or a script for psql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental roadblock is that DDL commands ("utility statements") do not allow parameter substitution at all. You need to build the query string and execute it.

#### Generic SQL

I suggest `format()` for the task:

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('
   CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq_tmp
   INCREMENT 1
   START %1$s
   MINVALUE %1$s'
 , (SELECT max(tmp.id)+1 FROM tmp));
END
$do$;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

> Another restriction on parameter symbols is that they only work in
> `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` commands. In other statement types
> (generically called utility statements), you must insert values
> textually even if they are just data values.

See:

- [“ERROR: there is no parameter $1” in “EXECUTE .. USING ..;” statement in plpgsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/121549/3684)
- [Creating user with password from variables in anonymous block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169566/creating-user-with-password-from-variables-in-anonymous-block/49175321#49175321)

#### Operating from psql

While working from psql you can use [`\gexec`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) to execute a the dynamically built DDL statement directly:

```sql
SELECT format('CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq_tmp INCREMENT 1 START %1$s MINVALUE %1$s', max(big_id)+1) FROM b2\gexec
```

See:

- [How to pass variable to PL/pgSQL code from the command line?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/240542/3684)
- [Filter column names from existing table for SQL DDL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61294986/filter-column-names-from-existing-table-for-sql-ddl-statement/61295255#61295255)

(Either way, if the table `tmp` can be empty, you need to do more, as the `SELECT` query comes up empty.)