# Converting varchar to int in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

so I am trying to convert a varchar to an int. I started without the numeric type and I got an error probably because of the `.` in the varchar. I searched online and found that I should add the numeric type. Now I have another error which is probably because of the `,` which is used as the thousands separator. Any suggestions?

I would like to use the alter table command if possible not cast or anything else because we have not learned it yet and it's for a school assignment. I have also added a screenshot of the query.

[image]

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE type USING column_name::type::type,
ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE type USING column_name::type::type;
```

Comment: I just realised how badly my attempt to write the query under the screenshot came out.Sorry for that, at least you can see it from the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you very much guys.The first answer worked for me.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 1):

You can use a number of ways to convert your text value to integer (assuming the number in text field is actually an integer). For example:

- `REPLACE(price, ',', '')::numeric::int`
- `TO_NUMBER(price, translate(price, '1234567890', '9999999999'))::int`

Your alter table statement should look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE calendar 
ALTER COLUMN price TYPE integer USING REPLACE(price , ',', '')::numeric::integer,
ALTER COLUMN adjusted_price TYPE integer USING REPLACE(adjusted_price, ',', '')::numeric::integer;
```

I've chosen the shorter way to cast, but TO_NUMBER case would work as well.

Comment: Well, slap me silly, I didn't know that was possible.  I've learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_number`, that can understand group separators:

```
ALTER TABLE calendar
   ALTER price TYPE integer
      USING to_number(price, '999,999,999,999.99')::integer,
   ALTER adjusted_price TYPE integer
      USING to_number(adjusted_price, '999,999,999,999.99')::integer;
```

Answer (score 0):

**My example/test script.**

```sql
-- █ Droping and creating the table for test purposes. Don't do this with table with production data.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS calendar;
CREATE TABLE calendar
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 100 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    price character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    adjusted_price character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_calendar_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- █ For test purposes, creating example data if table exists.
DO $$ -- DO executes an anonymous code block
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = 'calendar') THEN
        INSERT INTO calendar (price, adjusted_price) VALUES('8,000.00', '8,001.00');
        INSERT INTO calendar (price, adjusted_price) VALUES('7,000.00', '7,355.00');
    END IF;
END;
$$;

-- █ Alter table columns from varchar to int.
ALTER TABLE calendar
ALTER COLUMN price TYPE int USING SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(price, ',', ''), '.', 1)::int, 
ALTER COLUMN adjusted_price TYPE int USING SPLIT_PART(REPLACE(adjusted_price, ',', ''), '.', 1)::int;

-- REPLACE(source, old_text, new_text ) comma is replaced by empty string '8,000.00' -> '8000.00'
-- SPLIT_PART(string, delimiter, position) '8000.00' is splitted in 2 parts ['8000', '00'] we need the part 1 ->'8000'
-- ::int using cast operator ::, convert from varchar to int.

-- █ Select all columns with new types.
select * from calendar;
```

**Example data**

```
id  price       adjusted_price  
100 "8,000.00"  "8,001.00"
101 "7,000.00"  "7,355.00"
```

[image: calendar]

**After alter the table**

```
id  price   adjusted_price   
100 8000    8001  
101 7000    7355
```

[image: calendar]

**References**

PostgreSql [SPLIT_PART](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-split_part/)
PostgreSql [REPLACE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-replace/)
PostgreSql [CAST](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/)
PostgreSql [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html)
[Check if table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20584058/3158594)