# Relationship exists but the table didn't get created

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table, dbeaver

```
create table project_posts (
id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title varchar(100) not null,
body varchar(500) not null,
images bytea,
posted timestamp not null);
```

I ran this to create a table in my database and it worked fine, but the table doesn't appear under the tables folder and trying to select from it or drop it prompts the: "table does not exist" error.

The issue is that when I try to create the table again it tells me that the relationship `project_posts` already exists. Not only do I have no clue what caused this is the first place, I have no idea how to get rid of the relationship so that I can attempt to create the table again.

Comment: Please remember to report the verbatim error message for future questions. And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the error message says "relation", not "relationship". And that can be an index or some other relation. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-DESCRIPTION)

> The name of the table must be distinct from the name of any other
> table, sequence, index, view, or foreign table in the same schema.

Test with:

```sql
SELECT oid::regclass, relkind
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
WHERE  c.relname = 'project_posts';
```

Shows all objects of that name in all schemas. The name is displayed schema-qualified if not in the default schema. About the `search_path`:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

[The manual about `relkind`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html)

> `r` = ordinary table, `i` = index, `S` = sequence, `t` = TOAST table,
> `v` = view, `m` = materialized view, `c` = composite type, `f` =
> foreign table, `p` = partitioned table, `I` = partitioned index

Related:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema)

You might be able to rename or remove the competing relation. Else, you need a different name.