# Feedback on whether index was created on materialized views in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes

I created a unique index for a materialized view as :

```
create unique index if not exists matview_key on
      matview (some_group_id, some_description);
```

*I can't tell if it has been created*
How do I see the index?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you get an error? If not, the index was created.

Comment: In `psql` do: `\d matview`.

Comment: Option 2: `select * from pg_indexes where indexname = 'matview_key' and tablename = 'matview';`

Comment: That was awesome!

Comment: @AdrianKlaver If you think this could be useful to others, please can you write your comments as an answer? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to verify index creation:

```
--In psql
\d matview

--Using SQL

select 
  * 
from 
   pg_indexes 
where 
   indexname = 'matview_key' 
and 
   tablename = 'matview';
```

More information on [pg_indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-indexes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Like has been commented, if the command finishes successfully and you don't get an error message, the index was created. Possible caveat: while the transaction is not committed, nobody else can see it (except the unique name is reserved now), and it still might get rolled back. Check in a separate transaction to be sure.

To be absolutely sure:

```sql
SELECT pg_get_indexdef(oid)
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class
WHERE  relname = 'matview_key'
AND    relkind = 'i'
-- AND    relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace  -- optional, to make sure of the schema, too
```

This way you see whether an index of the given name exists, and also its exact definition to rule out a different index with the same name. Pure SQL, works from any client. (There is nothing special about an index on materialized views.)

Also filter for the schema to be *absolutely* sure. Would be the "default" schema (a.k.a. "current" schema) in your case, since you did not specify in the creation. See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Related:

- [Create index if it does not exist](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35626/3684)
- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

In psql:

```
\di public.matview_key
```

To only find *indexes*. Again, the schema is optional to narrow down.

#### Progress Reporting

If creating an index takes a long time, you can look up progress in [`pg_stat_progress_create_index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/progress-reporting.html#CREATE-INDEX-PROGRESS-REPORTING) since Postgres 12:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_progress_create_index
-- WHERE relid = 'public.matview'::regclass  -- optionally narrow down
```

Comment: Hello Erwin Brandstetter, Can you help me with this question. I believe you can solve it.......
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256034/psql-df-display-function-not-contain-certain-string-pattern?noredirect=1#comment124196464_70256034

Answer (score 0):

Un alternative to looking into `pg_indexes` is `pg_matviews` (for a materialized view only)

```
select *
from pg_matviews
where matviewname = 'my_matview_name';
```