# quote_ident() does not add quotes to column name "first"

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, identifier

I need to get a column name correctly wrapped in double quotes. `quote_ident()` does not seem to do it?

```
select 1 first; -- fails
select quote_ident('first'); -- produces first, not "first"
```

What command can I use to successfully quote an identifier. I am trying to dynamically build a `SELECT` statement with it:

```
SELECT 'select ' 
|| string_agg(
        case when udt_name in ('varchar', 'text')
            then 'left(' || quote_ident(column_name) || ', 65535) ' || quote_ident(column_name)
        else quote_ident(column_name)
        end, ',' order by ordinal_position) 
|| ' from "public"."MyTableName"'
FROM information_schema.columns c
join parse_ident('"public"."MyTableName"') t 
on t[1] = table_schema and t[2] = table_name
```

This is generating:

```
SELECT id, left(first, 65535) first from "public"."MyTableName";
```

Which blows up because first as a column name needs to be wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Don't omit `AS` key word for column aliases

> ```
> SELECT id, left(first, 65535) first from "public"."MyTableName";
> ```
>
> Which blows up because first as a column name needs to be wrapped in double quotes.

Not exactly. It blows up because you omitted the keyword **`AS`** where it should not be omitted.

This works:

```sql
SELECT 'select ' 
|| string_agg(
        case when udt_name in ('varchar', 'text')
            then 'left(' || quote_ident(column_name) || ', 65535) AS '  -- !!
              ||  quote_ident(column_name)
        else quote_ident(column_name)
        end, ', ' order by ordinal_position) 
|| ' from "public"."MyTableName"'
FROM information_schema.columns c
join parse_ident('"public"."MyTableName"') t 
on t[1] = table_schema and t[2] = table_name;
```

Produces:

```
SELECT id, left(first, 65535) AS first from "public"."MyTableName";
```

Which works as expected in turn.

The [manual about *"Omitting the AS Key Word"*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#id-1.9.3.171.10.5):

> In the SQL standard, the optional key word `AS` can be omitted before
> an output column name whenever the new column name is a valid column
> name (that is, not the same as any reserved keyword). PostgreSQL is
> slightly more restrictive: `AS` is required if the new column name
> matches any keyword at all, reserved or not. Recommended practice is
> to use AS or double-quote output column names, to prevent any possible
> conflict against future keyword additions.

It's OK to omit the keyword `AS` for table aliases, but not for column aliases.

`first` is not a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in Postgres. (It used to be "reserved" in the ancient SQL standard SQL-92, but not any more in standard SQL, either.) It is *"non-reserved"** to be precise. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html):

> Non-reserved key words only have a special meaning in particular contexts and can be used as identifiers in other contexts.

Omitting `AS` makes it just such a context.

**`quote_ident()`** works reliably. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)

> Returns the given string suitably quoted to be used as an identifier
> in an SQL statement string. Quotes are added only if necessary (i.e.,
> if the string contains non-identifier characters or would be
> case-folded). Embedded quotes are properly doubled.

`format()` with the specifier `%I` does the same.

Reserved words are not mentioned, but quoted properly regardless. To be precise: all key words marked *"reserved"* or *"(cannot be function or type)"* in the column "PostgreSQL" of [the *SQL Key Words* table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html#KEYWORDS-TABLE).

*I'll file a documentation bug to add that.*

#### To be absolutely sure: [`quote_all_identifiers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-QUOTE-ALL-IDENTIFIERS)

If you want to be absolutely sure and don't mind all the added noise, you can force Postgres to quote *all* identifiers with the configuration parameter `quote_all_identifiers`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-QUOTE-ALL-IDENTIFIERS)

> When the database generates SQL, force all identifiers to be quoted, even if they are not (currently) keywords.

That includes output from `quote_ident()` and `format()`. I would ***not*** do that, dreading all the added noise.

You might set the parameter locally with `SET LOCAL` in the same transaction. Like:

```sql
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL quote_all_identifiers = true;
SELECT ...
END;
```

#### Faster

That said, I would use `format()` and `concat()` and target the catalog table `pg_attribute` instead: cleaner, simpler, faster. But not portable to other RDBMS:

```sql
SELECT format('SELECT %s FROM %s;'
            , string_agg(CASE WHEN atttypid = ANY ('{text, bpchar, varchar}'::regtype[])
                              THEN concat('left(', col, ', 65535) AS ', col)
                              ELSE col END, ', ')
            , attrelid)
FROM  (
   SELECT attrelid::regclass, atttypid, quote_ident(attname) AS col
   FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = 'public."MyTableName"'::regclass  -- provide once, optionally schema-qualified
   AND    attnum > 0
   AND    NOT attisdropped
   ORDER  BY attnum
   ) sub
GROUP  BY attrelid;
```

Produces:

```
SELECT id, left(first, 65535) AS first FROM "MyTableName";
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4e45f27f16714c53c73e6e0df707c295)*

Notably, ...

- ... you only need to provide the table name once, optionally schema-qualified.
- ... if the table does not exist, the query fails immediately with a helpful error message.
- ... the output table name is only schema-qualified and double-quoted where necessary.
- ... this also covers `character(N)` (internal name `bpchar`).

Further reading:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)
- [Truncating display by default in postgres psql select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875295/truncating-display-by-default-in-postgres-psql-select-statements/34446754#34446754)
- [PostgreSQL force upper case for all data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102998/3684)
- [Check whether empty strings are present in character-type columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82030/3684)

Comment: Damn thanks. The first sentence would have been enough, but damn. Thanks.